# Adding a network card to Dell's PowerEdge R210

Tags: networking, dell-poweredge

The PowerEdge R210 comes with 2 network slots out of the box (+ another one for iDRAC).
Is there a way to add another card to have an extra gegabit ethernet slot?

Answer (score 1):

I've put a few of those little guys in-- they're very cute little boxes and reasonably inexpensive.

Dell will sell you addt'l NICs at time of purchase. Otherwise, you'd need an Ethernet NIC compatible with the PCIe 16x slot. The list of NICs that Dell will sell at time of purchase is a decent list to pick from:

- Intel PRO 1000PT 1GbE Single Port NIC, PCIe-1
- Intel Gigabit ET Dual Port NIC, PCIe-4
- Broadcom 5709 Dual Port 1GbE NIC w/TOE PCIe-4
- Intel Gigabit ET Quad Port NIC, PCIe-4
- Broadcom 5709 Dual Port 1GbE NIC w/TOE iSCSI, PCIe-4

Any of those would do what you want and will physically fit in the box.

Comment: but there isn't any free slot (or it hides very well)...

Comment: I believe there is one PCIe x16 slot, as Evan stated.

Comment: The specs at Dell's site show that it has a PCIe slot and I've got at least on R210 on a Customer site w/ an add-in PCIe SCSI controller in that slot. You may want to talk to your Dell sales rep or Dell technical support so they can help steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Apparently the only PCIe slot is occupied by Dell's SAS 6/iR integrated RAID controller. Any suggestions?